# Update/Insert to a table in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update, upsert

I have two tables:

**TableA**

```
column0 int identity,
Key1 varchar(50),
Key2 varchar(50),
Column3 varchar(50)
```

**TableB**

```
Key1 varchar(50),
Key2 varchar(50),
Column3 varchar(50)
```

Now I have to insert/update into `TableB` from `TableA` depending on the `Key1` and `Key2` columns. Also not all records in `TableA` can be considered. Only the records with the MAX identity(column0) value when grouped by `key1,key2` need to be considered.

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using (MySQL, SQL Server, PostreSQL, ...)? Also, I recommend you read [this article](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: I've joined the two tables and updated the records in the target table that need to be updated. I now dont know how to deal with the inserts. Because the records that got updated are still in TableA.And I could delete the records in TableA as I make the updates in TableB. But this would still leave out records in TableA that are lesser than MAX(column0) per group.

Comment: I'm using SQL Server.

Comment: Please provide a sample of the data and the code you tried and also try to be more specific in the question or you will not get any answer...

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below query:

```
--update part
update b
set b.Column3=t.Column3
 tblB b inner join
 (select *, row_number() over(partition by Key1,Key2 order by Column0 desc)  as r from tblA) t 
on t.Key1=b.Key1 and t.Key2 =b.key2
where r=1 
--insert part
insert into tblB(Key1,Key2,Column3)
Select t.key1,t.Key2,t.Column3 
from tblB b right join
 (select *, row_number() over(partition by Key1,Key2 order by Column0 desc)  as r from tblA) t 
on t.Key1=b.Key1 and t.Key2 =b.key2
where r=1 and b.Key1 is NULL and b.Key2 is NULL
```